# Ripper algorithm on large data sets

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I've got a supervised learning problem where I've got about 15 features, mostly numeric, and I'm mapping these to a set of 5-7classes. Using decision trees or forests, I'm able to get confusion matrices that I'm quite satisfied with, but I'm interested in seeing what the "top" rules RIPPER would find would be.

I've been attempting to train on a small subset of the data, about 2 million rows (Again 15 features), but I find myself unable to actually generate a model via JRip as I always run into memory constraints after 6-7 hours of Weka's JRip churning. (Even on large EC2 instances)

Has anyone had success using RIPPER on large-ish data sets? Would I find more success 'bucketing' my numeric attributes first? Are there any important preprocessing steps I'm missing?